# External resources with rasterizeHTML

Tags: javascript

i used `rasterizeHTML` libary to render html to canvas, but i can't draw correct html/css. it's ignore the `External CSS`, it's render html not css ? Can you help the resolve this problem ?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    html_container = document.getElementById("thehtml"),
    html = html_container.innerHTML;

rasterizeHTML.drawHTML(html, canvas);
```

```css
* {
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 0;
}
.test {
  color: green;
  border: 2px dashed blue;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="200" style="border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>

<div id="thehtml" style="display: none;">
    <div class="test">Some example HTML</div>
</div>
```

** this libary not support in Microsoft Edge and IE ? if that's true can you help me find other libary ?
Thank.

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: i updated demo/snippet, Thank.

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow_

Comment: Provided snippet will work fine in all the __HTML5__ supported browsers..

Comment: @RayonDabre it's working but it's not bind css to canvas. Thank

Comment: As written in the [project's page](http://cburgmer.github.io/rasterizeHTML.js/) "However IE up to version 11 does not honour <foreignObject> and is unsupported.". Note that latest versions of Safari does suffer the same security restriction. Also, rendering of HTML elements passed to this technique do vary a lot. IMO, not usable, html2canvas is probably still the best tool for it. And for your external css problem, be sure your stylesheets are loaded while satisfying cross-origin policies.

Comment: @Kaiido OK thank you.